# Cells in XamDataGrid randomly changing background color

Tags: c#, xamdatagrid

I have a XamDataGrid where I change the background color of a cell if its value has been changed by the user, like this:

```
var result = touchpad.ShowDialog();
if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
{
     if (valueHasChanged)
     {
         var presenter = CellValuePresenter.FromCell(activeCell);
         presenter.Background = _changedCellBackgroundBrush;
     }
}
```

Now this works and the background of the cells that has been changed get the color I want them to have. However, if I scroll around in my table, sometimes it happens that random other cells also change its background color to my custom color or cells with my color have their background color changed back to the default color.

The code above is never called though, I checked by setting a breakpoint. And the above lines are the only place in my program where I set the custom background color.

Is that a refresh problem? Do I need to refresh my grid when scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue with the row selector checkbox being randomly selected on other rows as I scrolled around.  It is an issue with the cell virtualization since not all rows are created until actually being scrolled into view and cells are recycled, causing your background to be used on a cell that wasn't edited.

I fixed it by adding the RecordContainerGenerationMode element:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="SummaryDataGrid" DataSource="{Binding Summaries}" RecordContainerGenerationMode="LazyLoad" GroupByAreaLocation="None">
```